# Why does xelatex not want to be called by popen3 in vararg form?

Tags: ruby, xelatex, popen3

Take this minimal LaTeX document:

```
% minimal.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Hello World!
\end{document}
```

And this Ruby (2.5.1) script:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3(
  'xelatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '"minimal.tex"'
) do |_stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    log = stdout.readlines + stderr.readlines
    exit_status = wait_thr.value

    puts exit_status
    puts log.join('').strip!
end
```

Running the script, we get:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex)
...
! I can't find file `'"minimal.tex"''.
```

This is surprising. Not only because the file *is* there, but because both

- `Open3.popen3('xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode "minimal.tex"') do ...` *and*
- `Open3.popen3('lualatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '"minimal.tex"') do ...`

work just fine!

What is special about the combination of `xelatex` and `popen3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
Open3.popen3(
  'xelatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', 'minimal.tex'
)
```

works fine.

The error message tells you, the file `"minimal.tex"` does not exist.

With the varargs form of popen3, the `commands` array is passed to `Process#spawn` where `xelatex` is called with `arg1=-interaction=nonstopmode` and `arg2=minimal.tex`. The arguments are not passed to the shell. Side note, this way you can also call other processes with "complex" args, e.g. `Open3.popen3('mkdir', 'directory with spaces and $SHELL')`.

Ad `Open3.popen3('xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode "minimal.tex"')`: here, the entire string is considered a command that is sent to the standard shell, and this shell takes care of the double quotes.

Ad `Open3.popen3('lualatex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '"minimal.tex"')`: here I can only guess that lualatex ignores the double quotes.

See also: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-exec